# System with Gauss method, not very good

Tags: equations, alignment

I'd like to do this with LaTeX (or tikz maybe)?
[image]

For the first step, I can do it with array:

```
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
3x-2y & = & 4 \\
5x+3y & = & 9 \\
\end{array}
\right|
\begin{array}{c}
.3 \\
. 2
\end{array} $$
```

But for the second step, it gets much more complicated...

```
$\left\{
\begin{array}{ccccc}
9x & & -6y & = & 12 \\
+ & & + & &+\\
10x & + & 6y & = & 18 \\
\end{array}
\right . \\
\left.
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\hline
\; 19x & &  & \hspace*{1.3cm} = & 30\\
\; x & &   & \hspace*{1.3cm} = & \dfrac{30}{19}\\
\end{array}
\right.$
```

Do you guys have a better solution?

Here's my result with this:

[image]

Thank you for help!

Comment: Please edit your question to include code rather then images of code, people won't help unless they're bored as to even get to the point of trialing solutions, your entire document needs building from scratch and from small images. Copy and paste a small piece of code that can compile please, it'll help people help you quicker :)

Comment: @JamesT Done      : )